# Peer To Peer (P2P) Sync and Share Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, sync

I want to Share files across my network and on remote sites, So i am looking for **p2p**  **Sync/sharing** application. Just like Ubuntu One & Drop box , but it does not have **p2p** protocol.I want p2p because i want to **save bandwidth** on my local network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### [image]    [@ The Killer @](https://www.aerofs.com/)

If you want video tutorial [**Jupiter Broadcasting**](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/37056/bittorrent-sync-vs-aerofs-las-s26e10/)

---

> **what’s AeroFS?**

AeroFS is almost the same, with a small catch: there’s no central server. It’s peer-to-peer sync that works almost just like Dropbox. You can sync files between your own computers, or share folders with friends and colleagues, over the internet or inside your own network **when you’re offline**. You’ll still need an account for authentication, but after that, you don’t use the AeroFS servers at all.

AeroFS is like a magic folder. Anything you place in AeroFS will automatically sync between your personal devices, and anyone you invite to share with you.

> **Fast**

AeroFS Sync is FAST. Because AeroFS does not depend on the public cloud, data syncs directly between devices at the maximum speeds possible. That means that AeroFS works incredibly well not only over the internet, but on a **LAN** as well.

> **Private**

Your data never resides on our own servers. Everything you sync using AeroFS is private, and will only be shared with people you explicitly invite. This makes AeroFS the perfect tool for your sensitive data.

> **Unlimited**

With AeroFS you and your team can sync as much data as you need, for free. Whether it's 10GB, 100GB, or 1TB, AeroFS lets you sync all the data, to all of your devices. No caps, no file size limits.

> **Your data is safe**

AeroFS uses AES-256 with 2048-bit RSA to encrypt your valuable data between you and your collaborators. Because our encryption is end-to-end, even we, the service provider, can't see your data.

> **Supported OS's**

Linux, Windows, Mac, Android

[image]

> [Fore More Features](https://aerofs.com/features)

---

> **Installation & Configuration**

1. You need to create an account https://aerofs.com/
2. Download the Ubuntu installer, Click on client application ( Just double click it, it will open in software center )
3. After Installation is complete open AeroFs from Dash & Sign in [image]

[image]

> After log in to your AerFs account and check the newly devices

[image]

> I am syncing files from Ubuntu to Samsung Galaxy Tab

---

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a paid advertisement? Also, I can't see anywhere that says that this is P2P. If it's not, it doesn't answer the question. If it *is* P2P, then what are you paying $10/month for??

Comment: @naught101 when I wrote the answer they have free account of 5 devices on 1 account. yes it is P2P

Answer (score 7):

## [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/)

Blurb:

> Syncthing replaces proprietary sync and cloud services with something open, trustworthy and decentralized. Your data is your data alone and you deserve to choose where it is stored, if it is shared with some third party and how it's transmitted over the Internet.

It's a file syncing app that is

- **free & open-source** – unlike Dropbox/Resilio/AeroFS
- **secure** – all communication is encrypted, nodes are authenticated using certificates
- **decentralized/P2P** – there is no central server that can log things or go down when you least need it, each computer is its own server
- **simple** – you don't need to remember IP addresses or get a domain name, you just enter the Syncthing-identifier of the computer you want to pair with and Syncthing figures out the details
- **portable** – runs on Windows, Linux (including Ubuntu Touch), Mac, BSD, Solaris; there are also apps for Android and iOS.

[image]

---

### Installation:

The official Syncthing app can be installed on Ubuntu like this:

```
curl -s https://syncthing.net/release-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing release" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syncthing syncthing-inotify
```

To have it start for your user on startup, and start it immediately:

```
sudo systemctl enable syncthing@$USER.service
sudo systemctl start syncthing@$USER.service
```

You should now be able to open http://localhost:8384 and add folder shares, or other computers you want to share with. (Note: if you have several users, the other users will get different port numbers; check out the `<gui>/<address>` element in `~/.config/syncthing.config.xml` where the address to the web gui is stored.)

---

There is also a GTK app for those who prefer a more traditional feel: https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-gtk#syncthing-gtk

Answer (score 6):

### Bittorrent Sync

It's still experimental, but **Bittorrent Sync** may be the thing you want. It's p2p and is well documented. Get all information here: 
http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html

Bittorrent Sync works on Windows, Mac, BSD, Andoid, iOS and Linux (even on ARM and PowerPC processors).

I use it since a few months and can say it works reliable, even though we use it to collaborate between 3 users and more than 7 devices. One of them is a Raspberry Pi that is "always on". There are Repositories for Ubuntu and Debian with a server-version and a user version.
See here:

http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/19560-debian-and-ubuntu-desktop-packages-for-bittorrent-sync/

### Dropbox

Dropbox is not p2p and offers limited storage, but it supports local sync (=network sync) by default, so you'll save bandwidth on local networks. It also offers a command line tool, so you can use it on servers etc. It also offers version control via the webinterface.
https://www.dropbox.com/

---

Canonicals Ubuntu One does not support network sync yet: 
 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/375302

Comment: Despite the nice formatting of the aerofs answer, it just hasn't been a reliable performer on Linux (or Windows for that matter).  btsync has (far) less functional conflict resolution... but in terms of actually getting the initial sync done for a large amount of files (in number and size) as well as not mysteriously closing... btsync is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)** for bidirectional syncing of files based on profiles.

**Downside:** It's not an automatic filesharing tool, so you have to manually sync or make a cronjob.

**Upside:** It's very reliable and resolving conflicts works perfectly when doing manually with the graphical user interface.

You can install unison-gtk via the Ubuntu Software Center or via the command line with `sudo apt-get install  unison-gtk`

PS: You should under no circumstances use SparkleShare. I have been (trying to) using it for half a year now and the cpu usage randomly goes up to 100% and you often have to resolve conflicts in the git repository yourself.