# File transfer to smartphones from Ubuntu does not work properly

Tags: android, mtp

Modern smartphones are no longer USB based mass storage, MTP is used instead. This is not good. I want to move music and folders to my phone just normal filetransfers deleting renaming copy folders etc.

In Ubuntu 12.10 I can not make file transfer to my phone because MTP is not supported, gMTP does not work, Airdroid works but is slow, and not user friendly. Ubuntu "sees" my phone but I can not do anything.

Ubuntu 13.04 I can copy to the phone one file at the time, not a folder, not huge amounts of data.

This is not good enough. Airdroid or Dropbox is usefull but to slow and not user friendly.

Comment: Simply send files by bluetooth.

Comment: As an alternative you can use AeroFS http://askubuntu.com/questions/294916/peer-to-peer-p2p-sync-and-share-ubuntu

Comment: Please don't ask two questions. Ask a new question for your Nautilus problem.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE why did you edited the question & removed the question regarding nautilus? Ask the op to do. Please read what you should edit - http://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit

Comment: @Web-E cause the title has nothing to do with Nautilus or the Nautilus Dual Pane view, also it should be a seperate question. I think it's wrong if you answer the second Nautilus question here, because the people could think this is tolerated. You should make a comment to ask seperate question and then answer it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `go-mtpfs`, a FUSE filesystem that helps MTP users greatly.

You can do so, by adding a ppa and installing it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/unstable && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
```

There  is a custom script to so that you can easily mount them

```
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs-unity
```

More details see - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html