# Can I use Ubuntu One to offer SaaS and IaaS services?

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud, storage

I'm thinking about the possibility of using Ubuntu One free version (?) to offer SaaS and IaaS services. I do not know if Ubuntu One would be a good alternative to start with. What I wonder about the Ubuntu One free version is: if it allows execution of software and using some space on it to store data for free, and if it's possible, to what extent is it allowed.

Does anyone know, or has anyone used this service for free?

Comment: Not an answer to your question just have a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/294916/peer-to-peer-p2p-sync-and-share-ubuntu/295103#295103

Answer (score 2):

No. Ubuntu One is simply a cloud storage service. It doesn't work in the ways you'd want it to for SaaS or IaaS. for what you're trying to do you'd either have to set up your own server or buy some space from amazon or the like and manage it with openStack and juju for example

Comment: Yeah i got it now, i think so, many thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you meant by "if it allows execution of software". However, as a free user, I can confirm that Ubuntu One provides 5 gigabytes of free storage. For comparison, Google Drive gives you 5GB of storage free, but has no Linux client. Dropbox gives you 2GB free and Copy (a newer player) provides 5GB free. Dropbox and Copy also have Linux clients.

Comment: Nice, it's clear to me now, thank you very much, i thought it could be like a mini-amazon cloud service for free, just to be sure.