# how to make Ubuntu One app synchronize outwards only (only remote be updated) (one directional)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

Is there some way to make Ubuntu One synchronize only outwardly (from local to remote only)?

So, when I make a change on my local file, it be updated remotely on Ubuntu One. But if the file is changed remotely or deleted, it is not synchronized on my local machine, and instead of that, the remote is updated again with my local copy.

I think this can be called one-directional synchronization.

Comment: Yes it can be done Bittorrent Sync with http://askubuntu.com/questions/294916/peer-to-peer-p2p-sync-and-share-ubuntu not with Ubuntu one

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Ubuntu One file synchronization is a file synchronization service, and not a remote storage or backup service.

However, it is possible to disable the file synchronization service, and write a program which uses the REST API to only do file uploads to the service, rather than synchronization.

Comment: I ended making a bash script that copies individual files to "Ubuntu One" folder with the same structure of my home folder, so only a copy is uploaded (synchronized). It also checks for changes on such files to update them at Ubuntu One. I integrated it into nautilus too and can also select multiple files (but not folders).