# sharing a 1 GB file that can be stream more then 10 computer

Tags: networking

i want to share a AVI file which capacity is 1 GB and my os is linux ubuntu 12.10 via a wireless Router by the name of TP-link .
i want to share this file and at least 10 computer capable to play the file simultaneously

can every one  help me to share this file consider that i share it via samba and appache2 but i cant stream or play more then one or two computer

thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest you that you should share it Peer-to-peer http://askubuntu.com/questions/294916/peer-to-peer-p2p-sync-and-share-ubuntu/295103#295103, it will use your & other pc network bandwidth as well...

Comment: What bitrate is that video encoded? 10 clients may eat up your bandwith.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Network File System (NFS) to share a directory and place the file in it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Comment: AVI file which capacity is 1 GB via a wireless Router & share this file and at least 10 computer capable to play the file simultaneously, ********* Are you sure about NFS ? **************

Comment: I have streamed a video file on 2-3 devices and it has worked, not sure about 10. Yes, I would agree with P2P for 10.

Comment: no i didn't share via NFS plz guide me step by step if possible

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for your needs is a media streaming solution like [this](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) project. Have you calculated the bandwidth needs for what you are trying to do? A high quality mpeg-4 stream can reach 4MBp/s per channel. Multiplying this by 10 leaves precious little room for anything else on a standard WiFi channel.