# How to share files between two machines in a network with a router?

Tags: networking, files, debian

I have a notebook with ubuntu 13.04 and a desktop with Debian 7.1.0 and I want to know how can I share files between the two machines, I'm using a router and the notebook is connected to the wireless network, since the desktop is on eth0. Can someone tell me how to share files betwen the two? Because I know absolutely nothing of networks. Thanks to those who respond.

Comment: I have a friend who uses sshfs for Linux to Linux connectivity.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "sharing"?

If you just want to download a small number of files from one computer to another, you can run `python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001` in the directory of the files to be shared on one computer. Then on another computer, use your browser (or other tools like `wget`) to navigate to the url `http://x.x.x.x:8001/` to view/download the files. `x.x.x.x` is to be replaced by the IP address of the former computer.

If you have a large number of files to copy, I suggest rsync though ssh. But it works well if you have ssh server up and running at least one computer.

If you want more complicated sharing, you may want to try NFS or sshfs.

Comment: Wow, I never knew you can set up a temporary HTTP server that easily, and always ended up downloading apache. This is certainly very handy!

Answer (score 1):

On nautilus you can right click the folder and choose share options. This will install the required software and share the folder using samba. This share will be visible form linux, windows and mac.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. Everything has it's advantages. This is a good one that should be mentioned. Very easy to set up.

## Bittorrent Sync

I recommend BTS especially for very big files like videos or so. It's easy to use and also can work over the internet (by default). It is similar to Dropbox (syncs folders), but without a central server. Available for Win, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS. More Information in this answer: [Peer To Peer (P2P) Sync and Share Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294916/peer-to-peer-p2p-sync-and-share-ubuntu/294985#294985)

Answer (score 0):

Patterson Eaglesoft is very picky!

On the XP server machine, go to:

My computer
Tools
Folder options
View
Uncheck Simple file sharing
Go to your Data folder
Sharing
Share the folder
Make sure that everyone has full control

Should work now.  If not on the remote PC, go the the technical reference, data base setup and type Host=name of server PC.  Example. Host=dell1525

Answer (score 0):

SYNCTHING

This is an opensource alternative to dropbox, Google-drive, etc, and like Bittorrent Sync, does not require storing your data on a third party server (something I once heard referred to as "running naked through the google-plex". An apt description I think). It is also cross platform. Linux, Windows, Apple, Android. Once installed and set up, you create a folder on each machine, exchange ID keys and they stay in sync. Changes in any one are reflected across all, data being exchanged/synchronized at any time the two (or more) machines are online at the same time. If you have a home server (raspberry pi with a large HDD attached ??) that is online all the time, you can have a fully private dropbox equivalent.

check it out for yourself here:

https://docs.syncthing.net

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to just use a flash drive to transfer files.  You could also upload your files to the cloud(eg: Google Drive, Dropbox, Ubuntu One, ect.) and download them on your other computer.