# How to access to synchronized folders via BitTorrent Sync?

Tags: sync, bittorrent

Good day people!
I installed Bittorrent Sync by this  manual '[How to run BitTorrent Sync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284683/how-to-run-bittorrent-sync)' (first way). After synchronization with my remote computer by Bittorrent Sync, I got folder with only root access. I restored full access by this script:

```
sudo chmod -R rwx+ugo /path/to/folder
```

but I do not want to do this operation after each synchronization. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz4cWCRdOj4
Did not have any problems with the folder as you have to specify it yourself in
web interface. No terminal commands needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, it is can be usefull if I used second way  from manual. But I am using ppa. Package contains configured daemon for this.

Comment: I found nothing better than your answer