# Why Evince is not generating thumbnails for .ai files in CDs or Pendrives?

Tags: usb-drive, evince, adobe, thumbnails

Recently, I discover that Evince (Ubuntu Document Viewer) could display Adobe Ilustrator files from old Clipart CDs (version 3 or less)

After appending these mime types: application/illustrator;image/ai; to the file "evince.thumbnailer" (in the folder usr/share/thumbnailers), Evince could generate thumbnails for .ai files (version 3 or less) only if this .ai file is copied in the Hard Disk, not directly from CDs or USB pendrives.

How could I make that Evince generates thumbnails for .ai files directly from USB pendrives or CDs?

Actually, Evince could generate thumbnails from most (not all) .wmf files in clipart CDs without any kind of problems.

Could be that some security setting is blocking thumbnail generation of .ai files in CDs and Pendrives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/410696/image-preview-from-remote-drive ; please try the first solution on that question and see if it helps

Comment: The first solution does not works in my setup: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64x.

If I copy a folder of .ai files to my hard disk, Evince creates all thumbnails correctly, but the same folder in a CD or USB Pendrive only show generic icons. 

Look this image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ja3Yvw8cHLajB0TWhfRnM4Qms/view?usp=sharing