# How to Handle BTsync GUI in Ubuntu 14.04 with Small Displays?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, btsync

I would like to handle BTSync GUI in Ubuntu 14.04 in small displays. 
I would like to do this without installation Additions in Virtual environments such as VirtalBox. 
I downloaded BTsync [here](https://www.getsync.com/platforms/desktop) 64 bit without glibc, extracted it in Desktop and started the client by `./btsync`. 
BTsync's GUI is limited when used with small screen (< 7") in Ubuntu Linux. 
I cannot get forward in the GUI in the stage

[image]

where you see that there is no y-axis scrollbar in the right. So I cannot move downwards by two-fingers like in other views. 
I think this is a bug in BTsync's frontend that causes most complications in limited view environments like running the software in VirtualBox's Ubuntu where I have about 5" screen/display size because of memory limitations. 
VirtualBox is here just a test environment and I can reproduce the bug in running Ubuntu in embedded systems of small displays.

The bug is specific to Linux because they have unique login through the internet browser.

I successfully created the user ID just before going to the view in the screenshot; however, I cannot get forward as described above. 
I cannot completely see the view below in the internet browser. 
I am running VirtualBox inside OS X El Capitan.

How can you pass the view in the internet browser by some Terminal command? I keep the phase of adding user account and having a welcome screen in BTsync redundant. It would be great to setup the account in Terminal instead. 
I would just like to link the BTsync to existing circle so probable command is `btsync --config <path>`.

---

How can you Handle BTSync GUI in Ubuntu 14.04 with Small Displays?

Comment: Have you considered expanding the display size in the VM so that it can be larger?  Definitely doable if you install guest additions to the VM.

Comment: The tools you specify rely on having a somewhat later screen size - in VBox the graphics part of that is handled by the guest additions installed to the host (for VMware, it's VMware tools on the guest).  If you can't get the screen bigger you likely won't get the tools working right.  This is a problem for people on netbooks and real small screens too, by the way, so...

Comment: I don't know if this will work on OS/X, but you can move windows in Ubuntu by pressing ALT and moving the mouse (the cursor must be over the windows to be moved). If this shortcut doesn't conflict with some OS/X one, you should be able to move the browser window and access all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a ticket to the Developers of BTsync March/2016. They promised to pass the piece of information forward to developers, but did not promise any time to provide the simple fix.